# How to find unit vector with a positive first component?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\mathbb R^4$ have the Euclidean inner product. Find a unit vector with a positive first component that is orthogonal to all three of the following vectors.

**u** $= (1,-1,3,0)$, **v** $= (6,1,0,1)$, **w** $= (1,0,7,1)$

I keep getting $(-14, -77,-21,11)$ but obviously that is not a vector with positive first component. Can anyone show me how this is done?

Comment: How would you solve it with $2$ vectors in $3$-dimensional case (Hint: I would cross product. Then $\cdot (-1)$ if the first component is $<0$, then divide by the vector's norm)? Can it be extended to $4$ dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y,z,t)$ is orthogonal to $(1,-1,3,0)$, $(6,1,0,1),$ and $(1,0,7,1)$, then $$x-y+3z=0\tag1$$ $$6x+y+t=0\tag2$$ $$x+7z+t=0.\tag3$$

To eliminate $t$, subtract $(3)$ from $(2)$ to get $$5x+y-7z=0\tag4,$$ and  then, to eliminate $y$, add $(1)$ and $(4)$ to get $$6x-4z=0\tag5.$$

We will arbitrarily set $x=2$ to make the arithmetic easy and then scale later.

From $(5)$, we then get $z=3$; from $(1)$, we then get $y=11$,

and, from $(2)$ or $(3)$, we then get $t=-23$.

So we have $(x,y,z,t)=(2,11,3,-23)$, and now it just needs to be normalized.

I think this is essentially what [Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg) did, but with more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $(-14,-77,-21,11)$ is not orthogonal to $(1,-1,3,0)$ for example.

Take the following vector.  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2+11^2+3^2+23^2}}(2,11,3,-23).$$

Comment: Why don't you add a derivation? At least like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7Bt%2Cx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B6%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C7%2C1%7D%7D). Thanks.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I am ready to explain, how I got it. Did you check my answer?

Comment: Sure I did. The WA link above gives the same vector. All we have to is norm it to $1$ (your is already normed).

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I made it by hand.

Comment: If it's shorter than $4$ determinants of $3\times 3$ or orthonormalization (Gram-Schmidt) process or solving a system of $3$ equations I want to know how). Thanks.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I just solved the following system. $1-a+3b=0$, $6+a+c=0$ and $1+7b+c=0$, which is easy without matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the linear system system
$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{u} \\ \mathbf{v} \\ \mathbf{w}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 3 & 0 \\ 6 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 7 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t\end{bmatrix}$$
to obtain $$(x,y,z,t) = \alpha (2, 11, 3, -23), \quad\text{ for any $\alpha
\in\Bbb{R}$}.$$
Now pick any $\alpha > 0$ and there is your vector $(x,y,z,t) \perp \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ with $x>0$.